# Sort CSV File by first column using Batch command

Tags: sorting, batch-file, csv, batch-processing

How can I sort a csv file in order by the first column of data using a batch file? The first column contains alpha-numeric data.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Additional question

How can you ignore header line for the CSV?

Comment: Maybe i'm losing something, but, for the first column, what is the problem with `sort`?

Comment: It may need to be padded for sort to work.  But only the OP knows what data there is.

Comment: That worked fine, for some reason I thought there would be more to it eg: specifying the column and data type but I guess not! Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As MC ND commented, just type your file and pipe it to sort.

```
 type yourcsv.csv | sort
```

Comment: Or simpler yet: `sort yourcsv.csv`

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use sort command

sort yourfile.csv